# One Spring controller reusable to different views

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm developing a web site in which you can login from almost every page. The login action is the same to every page but always it must return to the page from which the action has been launched. My idea is to manage all the login request with the same Spring controller (make it reusable) and depends on the page that called it, forward to it.

I don't know if it is possible or if there is another way to accomplish my requirements without having to "copy" the same action on each controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each page, generate login link URL in such way that it includes return page URL. Then your login controller will know where to redirect after successful login.

For example on MyPage.html, login link will be `http://server/login.do?returnURL=MyPage.html`

Your controller will be attached to login.do and redirect at the end to `returnURL`.

Comment: Thanks. And what about if a need to call different controllers? I mean, as I'm going to redirect to different pages and these pages are populated by database calls on different controllers, I neither want to copy this functionality on login controller. So I think it could be resolved using forward to the appropiate controller based on the returnURL... I don't know if it is an elegant way to proceed...

Comment: Your login controller will decide where to redirect after success or failure. For this decision it will use parameter received in request. `returnURL` is one kind of parameter to make such decision but you can pass any other parameters of your choice. The parameter(s) like `returnURL` will be generated by the controller that returns the page that has login link/url. If you are concerned about duplicating the code that adds `returnURL` - well there are many methods to solve it. Put it in some utility class, for example.